# Non-closed output set of a complex function with a closed input set

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

The problem I am trying to understand is "Find an example of a set A $\subseteq$ $\Bbb{C}$ and continuous function f:A$\rightarrow$C that satisfies the following conditions: The set A is closed, but the set f(A) is not."

I know that the output set of a continuous function will be compact if the input set is compact, so I believe I will need to use an input set A which is closed but not bounded, such as the set A={z$\in$$\Bbb{C}$: 2<Imz<3}. I cannot think of a continuous function such that f(A) would not be closed though.

This is my first course in complex analysis and I am having some difficulty understanding this problem. I a looking for a possible solution to build intuition from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take $A=\Bbb C$ and $f=\exp$. Then $A$ is closed, but $f(A)=\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$, which is not closed. Another possibility (still with $A=\Bbb C$) consists in taking $f(z)=\frac1{1+|z|}$; then $f(A)=(0,1]$.

Comment: Would another possibility be $A=\Bbb{C}$ and $f=\frac1{z}$ since this would also give $f(A) = \Bbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$?

Comment: No. That makes no sense, since $f$ is undefined at $0$.